# Local Ruby/rails server for web scraping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to run some web scraping routines on my local mac, but the default rails server quickly consumes more than 1 gig of memory (only one request running for 5 hours). Is there a server that would be better suited for this?

Comment: Sinatra is a DSL for quickly creating web applications in Ruby. So may it consume less memory.

Comment: Scraping does not necessarily need a server. What do you use rails for in this context?

Comment: I am using the anemone gem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a web bot. Rails is too heavy.

A script using Nokigiri would be good enough. You can set cron to run the script.

If you want higher level things, Capybara could do, even it is for test mainly.

Comment: What language would the script be written in?

Comment: Isn't there a way to get the memory foot print of rails down a bit in this case?

Comment: You don't need Rails at all in this case. You can use gems alone in Ruby scripts.